# TastyPie throttling - by user or by IP?

Tags: python, django, tastypie, throttling

I can't seem to find any information on what TastyPie throttles based on. Is it by the IP of the request, or by the actual Django user object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throttle key is based on `authentication.get_identifier` function.

Default implementation of this function returns a combination of IP address and hostname.

**Edit**

Other implementations (i.e. BasicAuthentication, ApiKeyAuthentication) returns username of the currently logged user or `nouser` string.

Answer (score 2):

Tomasz is mostly right, but some of the authentication classes have a `get_identifier` method that returns the username of the currently logged in user, otherwise 'nouser'. I plan on standardizing this soon.